# PHP Building array from traversing a nested tree model

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a typical nested tree model and I want to build an array with a 'children' array based on the levels or depths, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  Here's what I have now:

```
while($this->tax->getTreeNext($nodes)) 
{

    $level = $this->tax->getTreeLevel($nodes);

    if($level != 0){
        echo $level . '-' . $current_level;
        if($level > $current_level){
            $terms[$i] = array(
                    'term_id' => $terms[$i-1]['term_id'],
                    'name' => $terms[$i-1]['name'],
                    'level' => $terms[$i-1]['level'],
                        'children'  => array(
                        'term_id'   => $nodes['row']['term_id'], 
                        'name'      => $nodes['row']['name'], 
                        'level'     => $level,               
                        )
                );

            unset($terms[$i-1]);
        }else{

            $terms[$i] = array(
                'term_id'   => $nodes['row']['term_id'], 
                'name'      => $nodes['row']['name'], 
                'level'     => $level
            );
        }

        $current_level = $level;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This works for a single child, but not if the children have children... any suggestions how to fix this?

Thank you!

Edit:

This is the latest that appears to be close to working:

```
function process(&$arr, &$prev_sub = null, $cur_depth = 1) {

  $cur_sub = array();
    while($line = current($arr)){
        if($line['depth'] < $cur_depth){
            return $cur_sub; 
        }elseif($line['depth'] > $cur_depth){


            $prev_sub = $this->process($arr, $cur_sub, $cur_depth + 1 );

        }else{

            $cur_sub[$line['term_id']] = array('term_id' => $line['term_id'], 'name' => $line['name']);
            $prev_sub =& $cur_sub[$line['term_id']];
            next($arr);
        }
    }
  return $cur_sub;
 }
```

The tree is passed into this with depth values associated to each node.  The current problem is with the `elseif($line['depth'] > $cur_depth)`. If a node has children, it only returns arrays for the children, but it does not include that nodes name or term_id.

Thank you!

Comment: recursion instead of iteration.

Comment: Not quite sure I get it... could you post an example?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on your data structure?  How is your tree defined and stored?

Comment: It's using two columns lft and rgt, pretty much a standard nested set from what I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not really get how your current data structures looks like, take a look at this trivial example of traversing a tree.

```
$treeRoot = $this->tax->getRoot();

$result = traverse($treeRoot, 0);

function traverse($root, $level){
 $arr = array();

 $arr['term_id'] = $root['row']['term_id'];
 $arr['name'] = $root['row']['name'];
 $arr['level'] = $level;

 while($child = $root->getNextChild()){
  $arr['children'][] = traverse($child, $level+1);
 }

 return $arr;
}
```

So you start at the tree root, and fill the first level of array. Then you continue with root's children, but you go one level deeper. You do exactly the same thing as with the root, you fill in the data and go to children's children. When you reach the bottom of the tree, the last (grandgrandgrand)child finds out it's got no children left, so it just returns itself(normal array) to its parent. That parent returns itself back to its parent, and so on, till you reach the root again.

And voilà, you've got yourself a nested array. Typically you'd leave this kind of structure as a tree, but since I do not know what exactly do you want your result to be (your provided no example), use the above code as a reference for your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks.. this seems exactly right, it's giving me an endless loop though.. not sure

Comment: Hm, strange. while() should stop it at the lowest level since leaf does not have any children, so the loop shouldn't be even executed. Try debugging and find out where it cycles, and update the question, I'll look into it.